# How do I split a list of dicts into seperate dicts

Tags: python, python-3.x

How do turn this:

```
list1 = [{'A': '1', 'B': '2', 'C': '3'}, {'D': '4', 'E': '5', 'F': '6'}, {'G': '7', 'H': '8', 'I': '9'}]
```

Into this:

```
dict1 = {'A': '1', 'B': '2', 'C': '3'}
dict2 = {'D': '4', 'E': '5', 'F': '6'}
dict3 = {'G': '7', 'H': '8', 'I': '9'}
```

Comment: See [Python lists](https://developers.google.com/edu/python/lists).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this.
But I would not suggest this way of coding.
Better define the variables you want explicitly instead of forming them on the fly.

```
list1 = [{'A': '1', 'B': '2', 'C': '3'}, {'D': '4', 'E': '5', 'F': '6'}, {'G': '7', 'H': '8', 'I': '9'}]
for i, j in enumerate(list1):
    exec(f'dict{i+1}={str(j)}')
print(dict1)
print(dict2)
print(dict3)
```

This way you can create as many variables as you want from the list

Answer (score 0):

This thing that you are trying to do is not good practise. Just use the original list of dict where ever you need it by indexing into it to get a specific dict: `list1[0]`, `list1[1]` etc.

or use a for loop to iterate through the list, and do "task" with each one.